# Can I search on metadata of my list or document library?

Tags: list, document-library, search

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have created a custom list and a custom document library. They have the same metadata fields (also metadata field and lookup fields). When I go to the list or document library I see a search box in the right upper window. When I search on a word I see results. The match was found in the column "Title". Is it also possible to get search results where the search engine is searching also in the metadata fields?

Comment: Searching a list or library already searches metadata fields, including lookup fields. (This is different from managed properties.) Did you try searching for something in a metadata field and it didn't get returned in search results?

Answer (score 0):

> You can enhance the end-user search experience by mapping crawled
>   properties to managed properties. Crawled properties are metadata
>   (such as author, title, or subject) that are extracted from documents
>   during crawls. Managed properties can appear in refined searches and
>   help users perform more successful queries.
>
> Refined searches can be performed only on managed properties, not
>   crawled properties. To make a crawled property available for refined
>   search queries, you must map the crawled property to a managed
>   property. You can map multiple crawled properties to a single managed
>   property or map a single crawled property to multiple managed
>   properties. If a managed property has multiple crawled properties
>   mapped to it, and a document contains values for more than one of the
>   crawled properties, the order in which the properties are mapped and
>   their priority determine the value of the managed property.

Kindly have a look this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff621097(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010 and FAST search. Is your solution possible in my environment?

Comment: Totes ma goat!!